# Sampling variance of the intercept in OLS

Tags: variance, least-squares, residuals

What is the difference between the sampling variance of the intercept and the residual variance, in an OLS model that fits just the intercept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sampling variance of the intercept is the variance of the parameter estimate, and the residual variance is the variance of the residuals.  In a model with only an intercept, the OLS estimate is just the sample mean, and its sampling variance will (typically) be estimated by $s^2/n$, where $s^2$ is the residual variance.

Comment: Can I get the sampling variance of the intercept from the SE of the intercept?

Comment: The standard error of a statistic is - by definition - the population standard deviation of the sampling distribution of the statistic. So the sampling variance would be its square.